# Accepting cookies is not cached on my Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, caching, cookies

I have activated a cookies plugin "Cookie Notice & Compliance for GDPR/CCPA" on my wordpress website. The cookies bar looks good and when I accept the cookies it dissappears (as it should).

However, when I go to another page (or refresh the page) the cookies bar appears again. My expectation is that the answer should be cached so the user doesn't have to answer it several times.

I'm using "WP-Optimize 3.2.6" as the cache plugin but can't figure out how to solve the problem. It seems like I should change something in the settings in the below. Any ideas what to do?
[image]

Comment: I've no answer to your question (we should know a lot more, it's a tricky one...) but I can guarantee you those setting will have no effect on your issue.

Comment: Thanks @RiccardoLV, what information do you need?

Comment: Taking for granted the issue is caused by the caching plugin, you don't have to prevent page caching if cookie XXX is present. You have to prevent cookie XXX to be cached, it's different. Of course cookie XXX is the "main" cookie left by the cookie plugin.

Comment: @RiccardoLV do you know what the "main" cookie left by the cookie plugin or how to find it? I tried to Google this without finding anything.

Comment: If you're a paid user of one of those 2 plugins you can reach the  help-desk. Otherwise you can create a topic in their respective free support forum at the wp plugin repositories (WP-optimize's one is here: https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/wp-optimize/ ). You can even try to find it yourself via any browser's developer tools.